# Select top dates grouped by ID's

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table as follows:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE
    (
    userID int,
    testID int,
    someDate datetime
    )
```

Within it I store dates along with two ID values, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO @tmp (userID, testID, someDate) VALUES (1, 50, '2010-10-01')
INSERT INTO @tmp (userID, testID, someDate) VALUES (1, 50, '2010-11-01')
INSERT INTO @tmp (userID, testID, someDate) VALUES (1, 50, '2010-12-01')
INSERT INTO @tmp (userID, testID, someDate) VALUES (2, 20, '2010-10-01')
INSERT INTO @tmp (userID, testID, someDate) VALUES (2, 20, '2010-11-01')
```

I need to select the latest date per userID/testID combination.  So, the result would be

```
userID  testID  someDate
1       50      2010-12-01
2       20      2010-11-01
```

It sounds really easy but I can't figure it out. [SQL Fiddle Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/5196).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT userID, testID, MAX(someDate)
FROM @tmp
GROUP BY testId,userID;
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/5209)

Comment: Just be wary of using this query on a table with more columns - columns that are neither grouped nor aggregated.

Comment: I've posted a revision to this question and would appreciate further help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424333/select-max-dates-plus-id-value

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT userId, testId, MAX(someDate)
FROM @tmp
GROUP BY testId, userId
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/5205

Comment: @EvilDr - no problem. I was just testing this on your SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Er - shurely shome mishtake

Comment: Well it relies completely on the fact that all the '2's equal 20 and all the '1's equal 50. What if a '2' equals '50'?

Comment: I still don't think it's a very scalable solution, but I gave you your point back.

Comment: @Strawberry - I'm intrigued to what you think is a more scalable?

Comment: 'scalable' in the sense of more columns, not more rows - I don't do mssql so I'm reluctant to post a solution but I think you have a TOP function for this!?!

Comment: @Strawberry - TOP will only bring back a limited number of rows, where the OP could have n number of test id'/user id's.  TOP can also be expensive to use.

Comment: Yes TOP didn't actually work when I tried it.  Anyway there's a new revision to debate on(!) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424333/select-max-dates-plus-id-value

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT t1.* FROM @tmp t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT userId, MAX(someDate) someDate
            FROM @tmp
            GROUP BY userId) t2
        ON t1.userId = t2.userId
       AND t1.someDate = t2.someDate
```