# Select MAX dates plus ID value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Please consider the following table...

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE
    (
    ID int,
    userID int,
    testID int,
    someDate datetime
    )
```

...containing the following values:

```
INSERT INTO @tmp (ID, userID, testID, someDate) VALUES (1, 1, 50, '2010-10-01')
INSERT INTO @tmp (ID, userID, testID, someDate) VALUES (2, 1, 50, '2010-11-01')
INSERT INTO @tmp (ID, userID, testID, someDate) VALUES (3, 1, 50, '2010-12-01')
INSERT INTO @tmp (ID, userID, testID, someDate) VALUES (4, 2, 20, '2010-10-01')
INSERT INTO @tmp (ID, userID, testID, someDate) VALUES (5, 2, 30, '2010-11-01')
INSERT INTO @tmp (ID, userID, testID, someDate) VALUES (6, 2, 20, '2012-11-01')
```

I need to retrieve the maximum date for each userID/testID combination of values, and also the accompanying ID value.  The results should be:

```
ID   userID  testID  someDate
-------------------------------
3    1       50      2010-12-01
5    2       30      2010-11-01
6    2       20      2012-11-01
```

When I try the following query, the result set becomes incorrect and all rows are shown.  I cannot omit ID from the GROUP BY clause because it causes and error.  Can anyone help please?  It seems long-winded to join the table to itself to get these values.

```
SELECT ID, userID, testID, MAX(someDate)
FROM @tmp
GROUP BY testId,userID,ID;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/5219

Comment: see answer for similar question on DBA.Stackexchange http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/how-to-get-the-max-row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try:

```
select * from (
    select 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by userID, testID order by SomeDate desc) Rnum 
    From @tmp
)x where Rnum=1
```